# May a New function allocate filedescriptors in Golang

Tags: go

As I come from a C and C++ background and golang is semantically different I have some discussions about function names "New" vs "Open" and what the programmer expects what to happen under the hood. I have created a package where the New function opens file descriptors to temporary files. I'm not sure this is intended behavior for APIs written in Go.

Here is a snippet:

```golang
// Not directly convenient New allocates file descriptors
deb := New()
deb.AddFile("/tmp/myfile")
deb.Write("/tmp/mypackage.deb")
deb.Close()

// Idiomatic it opens file descriptors but we have to provide context to open
info := &Props{Name: "mypackage"}
deb := info.Open("/tmp/mypackage.deb")
deb.AddFile("/tmp/myfile")
deb.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go's community is still finding its idioms and patterns, so don't consider anything dogma. Based on what I've seen in a year and a half, I don't think it's wrong to touch disk in a `New` function if it has godoc comments explaining the behavior. It *would* be unusual, and probably make more sense to touch the disk in `d.Write()`. Some common patterns I've seen with `New` functions:

- are only exported when designed for use by other packages
- makes sense when invoked from other packages with the package name prefixed: `d := deb.New(...)` (since you have a variable named `deb`, your package is something else)
- returns an instance of the package's main business logic, to be used further
- accept dependencies as arguments instead of constructing its own dependencies (hopefully any behavioral dependencies are interfaces)
- often a `main()` function assembles those dependencies, calls `d := deb.New(deps)`, and executes the behavior `d.AddFile(); d.Write(); d.Close()`

an example signature using an interface:

```
package deb

// New accepts blah returning a *Deb. It returns nil if blah.
func New(name string, to io.WriteCloser) *Deb {...}
```